# Why does the UTC time only appear in the achievement tab?

Tags: discussion, achievements-dialog, global-inbox

I was bored and started clicking the tabs of the top navBar, and then I noticed one thing that I cannot explain to myself:

[image: As you can see, UTC time is displayed in the achievements tab]

As you can see, UTC time is displayed in the achievements tab:

[image: But no in any other tabs]

But it is not displayed in any other tabs.

---

Is there a reason why does the UTC only appears in the achievement tab?

Comment: Perhaps because the achievements tab has "today", "yesterday" etc, and explicitly showing the UTC time makes it clearer that those day labels are relative to UTC?

Comment: The inbox also shows "yesterday".  Achievements was added much later.  I suspect that after 9 years, there is a fair chunk of code written by somebody that is no longer around that nobody wants to touch anymore :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reputation cap is based on UTC. Therefore, it's useful knowing what UTC is when looking at achievements, because it helps you determine if you're going to reach the reputation cap for that day. It isn't so useful for other tabs.

Comment: That's logical, and also prevents a loophole where a user can earn >200 reputation in a single day by changing their timezone via a VPN.

Comment: @cybermonkey The reputation cap is calculated by the server, who doesn't care about the user's time zone at all. I can't really imagine any plausible implementation which would trigger your loophole.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann That was in response to this answer, not the overall theme.

Comment: @cybermonkey I believe the stupidest thing any web app can do is use users time for anything. I have personally seen people's computers with dates in the 90s or the 60s.